# Missing PAGE_GUARD flag on the memory of stack for one windows application

Tags: windows, stack

[A few minutes after the application starts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vcgF.png)
[3 hours after the application starts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbljQ.png)

After 3 hours, the stack memory missing PAGE_GUARD flag for many thread. At this time, the stack memory cannot be increased correctly.

I don't have any ideas on this issue.